# Drag-and-drop file onto script in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, drag-and-drop

In Windows Explorer (and other file managers) if you drag a file onto a script/executable, then it runs the script/executable with that file as the first argument.

Is it possible to get a similar behaviour in Nautilus?
(Would I have to use .desktop files / launchers?)

How about other linux file managers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `.desktop` file with `EXEC=` entry.

See related feature request on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/174125) and [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64357).

Comment: Thanks for that. I googled extensively on this, and somehow missed these (really old!) feature requests. Of course, for a `.desktop` file [you can't use relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811032/using-relative-paths-for-gnome-launcher), but at least I can now drag-and-drop to execute my python script.

Comment: @Simon: you're welcome! :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't figure out your answer. Could you give more details (say, a sample .desktop name, where to store it, what name shall it have). Or give a link on relevant pages ? (the links given didn't help me).

Comment: @kebs my answer was from 2011 (i just edited it to remove a dead link pointing to Ubuntu Brainstorm that is no more). I just tried the `.desktop` solution again under Ubuntu 13.10 and it seems to not work anymore, maybe because the handling of drop-a-file-over-another-file has been removed from Nautilus. Not a big surprise, because of the major changes to Nautilus in Gnome 3.x ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_(file_manager)#History )

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'm running 12.04 for the LTS advantage, but this doesn't help. I'll probably post a question about this. Already 4 years as a happy linux user, but this is a major feature I miss from those Windows days... I find this so convenient, I can't figure out why it is so complicated to implement on gnome desktop.

Answer (score 4):

As of now with Ubuntu 14.04, the method of creating a .desktop file works again. For example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name[en_EN]=all2pdf
Exec=/bin/bash -c "IFS=$'\n'; args=(`( for f in %U; do echo $f; done ) | sort`); dir=(`dirname $args`); convert ${args[@]} $dir/convert.pdf "
```

Putting this code in a file "all2pdf.desktop" and making this file executable by

```
chmod u+x all2pdf.desktop
```

allows to drag some files on the icon named "all2pdf" and converting them into one single PDF file using "convert".

The example command is lengthy, but is also contains a remedy for the list of files always being in reverse order (regardless of the selection order of the files that are dragged).

I have just used the above method (i.e. the file) to create a number of PDF files with few pages each from a bigger set of single pictures that I created using "Scan Tailor". It worked just fine and because comments on the above answer do imply that creating a .desktop file might not work anymore I would like to share the above example.