# dropping file on the application desktop shorcut/desktop file does not launch the exe

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, drag-and-drop

I m not able to launch the application by dropping the associated file on the desktop file/application desktop shorcut. Is there any configuration I need to make.
This is my desktop entry file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-mymime
Name=GTKTest
Exec=/home/vipul.gupta/MyWorkspace2/GTKdir/GTKTest %f
```

I followed this link but there is no solution mentioned :[Drag-and-drop file onto script in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52789/drag-and-drop-file-onto-script-in-nautilus?_gl=1*ssxn7g*_ga*NjIyNzk3NDA0LjE2NjYyOTc5NTc.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4NzE4MjM4Mi4xMzcuMS4xNjg3MTg0MTA2LjAuMC4w)